# How to open Network share Project in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans-8

How to open Network share Project in Netbeans ??
My Php project is in another machine and project folder is shared
my question is how to create a php project at netbeans using shared project folder which is in another machine

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, under 'File' Tab - Select New Project.  The First step is to 'Choose Project' - i.e. PHP or HTMl type etc. Then in Second step, 'Name and Location' - You can select folder from network in 'Sources Folder'. Then just follow the steps to share the project from network.

Hope this helps...